# Python Gtk3 Button Activated by Enter or Space key

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

In the following code, pressing the Enter or Space key triggers the button.  How do you disable this behavior, so only mouse-clicks will trigger the buttons?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow():
    def __init__(self):

        self.mwin=Gtk.Window()
        self.mwin.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        self.button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2")
        self.button2.connect("clicked", self.on_button2_clicked)

        self.mybox=Gtk.Box()     
        self.mybox.add(self.button)
        self.mybox.add(self.button2)
        self.mwin.add(self.mybox)
     
    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Button 1 clicked")

    def on_button2_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Button 2 clicked")

    def main(self):
        self.mwin.connect("destroy",Gtk.main_quit)
        self.mwin.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

if __name__=='__main__':

  win = MyWindow()
  win.main()
```

Comment: This is part of a larger program that uses the Space, Enter and other keys for different functions, so I don't want the buttons to respond to any keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  There may be another solution, but this prevents the keyboard from being able to trigger the buttons.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow():
    def __init__(self):

        self.mwin=Gtk.Window()
        self.mwin.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        ####add this line to prevent keyboard from triggering button###
        self.button.set_can_focus(False)                              #
        ###############################################################

        self.button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2")
        self.button2.connect("clicked", self.on_button2_clicked)
        ####add this line to prevent keyboard from triggering button###
        self.button2.set_can_focus(False)                             #
        ###############################################################

        self.mybox=Gtk.Box()     
        self.mybox.add(self.button)
        self.mybox.add(self.button2)
        self.mwin.add(self.mybox)
     
    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Button 1 clicked")

    def on_button2_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Button 2 clicked")

    def main(self):
        self.mwin.connect("destroy",Gtk.main_quit)
        self.mwin.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

if __name__=='__main__':

  win = MyWindow()
  win.main()
```